# magnific popup modal closes on click

Tags: magnific-popup

I am trying to create a modal (won't close on 'esc' or 'click') popup with magnific popup.  But for some reason, the popup closes on click or esc.  I have followed examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/n6c5f/2/ and here: http://codepen.io/vemec/pen/JDsLl. Copying and pasting the exact code doesn't seem to work - the popup opens fine but closes on default events.

This is my current HTML:

```
<a href="#modal1" class="open-modal1">Open modal 1</a>

<div id="modal1" class="clean-modal mfp-hide">
TEST Modal popup
</div>
```

And JS:

```
jQuery('.open-modal1').magnificPopup({
type:'inline',
modal:true
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to current version of Magnific popup solved the issue.  Perhaps there was this was an issue w/ v0.8.7?  Either way, resolved.